# How can I align wrapped flex items to the ones in the row above?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make the icons responsive. I gave them `flex: 1` but it appears that the images below(the second row) extends upto the parents width as shown

[image]

I am expecting the 2nd row images to align same as the above images leaving a blank area as :

`| img | img | img | img | img |`

`| img | img |  x  |  x  |  x  |`

```css
.option-images {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  max-width: 200px; /* for demo only */
}

.option-images>div {
  flex: 1;
}

.change-img {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="option-images">
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This type of question is really about HTML and CSS, and not JSX. Please revise the demo above as needed to accurately show the problem.

Comment: Doesn't simply removing `flex: 1` resolve the issue?

Comment: If all your flex children are the same size you really don't need to give them a flex proportion.

Comment: Yes removing of `flex: 1` should work. Check forked react example here https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-lake-us99d1

Comment: @isherwood Removing ```flex: 1``` makes it look unresponsive and also when the screen size decreases the last element goes down making a pretty big gap at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CSS grid job

```css
.option-images {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(40px,1fr));
  gap: 5px;
  /* for demo only */
  width: 200px; 
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}
.change-img {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="option-images">
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img key={key} class="change-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" onClick={imageChange} />
  </div>
</div>
```